# pre-parse a file to remove text between comments with Reg-ex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file which is JSON but some times it contains comments within it. In order to deserialize it, I have to pre-parse it to remove anything between comments. So far I have made this reg, it doesnt remove the unwanted text.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();

string strRegex = @"\/\*.*|.*(\n\r)*\*\/";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
myRegex.Replace(text, "");
```

In the following, I need to ignore everthing between comments so for instance from the following data, my reg-ex should only return the last nodes which contains the value Carieer S018.

**Sample Data**

```
{
    "Orders": [     

/*******************CALIBRATORS*********************/   
        /*{
            "Carrier": "S018",
            "SampleType": "Calibrator",
            "Position": 1,
            "CalMaterialLotNumber": "31032UI00",
            "CalMaterialExpirationDate": "07-07-2014",
            "AssayNumber": 241,
            "AssayVersion": 29,
            "Dilution": 1,
            "Replicate": 2,
            "MasterLotNumber": "31914UI00",
            "PackSerialNumber": "00001",
            "Comment": "TSH Cal",
        },


        {
            "Carrier": "S005",
            "SampleType": "Calibrator",
            "Position": 1,
            "CalMaterialLotNumber": "31032UI00",
            "CalMaterialExpirationDate": "07-07-2014",
            "AssayNumber": 696,
            "AssayVersion": 1,
            "Dilution": 1,
            "Replicate": 2,
            "MasterLotNumber": "89000UN13",
            "PackSerialNumber": "10001",
            "Comment": "Troponin Cal",
        },


                {
            "Carrier": "G008",
            "SampleType": "Calibrator",
            "Position": 1,
            "CalMaterialLotNumber": "31032UI00",
            "CalMaterialExpirationDate": "07-07-2014",
            "AssayNumber": 685,
            "AssayVersion": 1,
            "Dilution": 1,
            "Replicate": 2,
            "MasterLotNumber": "32916UI00",
            "PackSerialNumber": "50001",
            "Comment": "Folate Cal",
        },*/    


/*********************CONTROLS**************************/   




/*********************SAMPLES**************************/




/*************CARRIER 1****************/
    /*************C: S018 P: 1*************/
    {
        "Carrier": "S018",
        "SampleType": "Specimen",
        "SID": "1",
        "Position": 1,
        "AssayNumber": 241,
        "AssayVersion": 29,
        "Dilution": 1,
        "Replicate": 4,
        "Comment": "Pool",
    },
```

Comment: Just parse it instead of using regular expressions. Way easier.

Comment: possible duplicate of [During de-serialization of JSON files exclude nodes which are commented off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462399/during-de-serialization-of-json-files-exclude-nodes-which-are-commented-off)

Comment: @LB I deleted the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string strRegex = @"\/\*.*\*\/";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Singleline;
```

Note the `RegexOptions.Singleline`.  The 'RegexOptions.Singleline' option interprets the entire input string as a single line, where `.`(dot) matches every character in the input string, including `\n`(newlines).

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/eC3nW5

Comment: This works, but you should point out that the OP can get into trouble if any valid JSON strings include the text `/*`.  For example: `{ "key": "string with /* in it */"}`.  Perfectly valid JSON, but will screw up this method :/  Unfortunately, there's no easy way around it.

Comment: @MElliott I used your regex and used single line option, i am still getting the same text back. I will debug more to see if there is something wrong with my code

Comment: @tamtam - Hmmm... It should work..  just as it does in the example - http://regex101.com/r/eC3nW5

Answer (score 1):

MElliott almost had it, but you need to make the greedy `.*` lazy instead, by adding `?`:

`string strRegex = @"\/\*.*?\*\/";`

A working code sample:

```
string text = @"{
    ""Orders"": [     

/*******************CALIBRATORS*********************/   
        {
            ""Carrier"": ""S018"",
            ""SampleType"": ""Calibrator"",
            ""Position"": 1,
            ""CalMaterialLotNumber"": ""31032UI00"",
            ""CalMaterialExpirationDate"": ""07-07-2014"",
            ""AssayNumber"": 241,
            ""AssayVersion"": 29,
            ""Dilution"": 1,
            ""Replicate"": 2,
            ""MasterLotNumber"": ""31914UI00"",
            ""PackSerialNumber"": ""00001"",
            ""Comment"": ""TSH Cal"",
        },

/*******************CALIBRATORS*********************/   

        {
            ""Carrier"": ""S005"",
            ""SampleType"": ""Calibrator"",
            ""Position"": 1,
            ""CalMaterialLotNumber"": ""31032UI00"",
            ""CalMaterialExpirationDate"": ""07-07-2014"",
            ""AssayNumber"": 696,
            ""AssayVersion"": 1,
            ""Dilution"": 1,
            ""Replicate"": 2,
            ""MasterLotNumber"": ""89000UN13"",
            /*""PackSerialNumber"": ""10001"",
            ""Comment"": ""Troponin Cal"",*/
        }
        ]}";

            string strRegex = @"\/\*.*?\*\/";
            RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Singleline;
            Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
            text = myRegex.Replace(text, "");
```